# Downloading from member area of a site programmatically with cURL

Tags: curl

This is the sort of link I want to download with:

```
http://username:password@example.com/dl/file.zip
```

Edit: stackoverflow seems to go weird with colons, its username-colon-password.

Now, if I log out of the website and use the URL pattern above, it successfully authenticates and I can successfully download the file.

I have this cURL script:

```
<?php
echo "Attempting to download...<br />";
$out = fopen("zip.zip", 'wb');
if ($out == FALSE){
 die('File could not be opened, exiting.');
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);

curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);
fclose($out);
?>
```

And for some reason, it just downloads a 0KB file. I'm pretty sure the coding is correct, but then it can't be if it's not working.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding follow locations option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

EDIT: Explanation
In my experience, a lot of download links are redirected to another link that actually contains the file.  Curl by default doesn't follow redirections, and requires the option to be enabled first.

To debug the problem, you can set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option, and then print the `curl_exec` results:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

If the header contains `Location: ...` parameter, then this is your problem.

Comment: I get this error: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set - which I'm thinking might be my problem?

Comment: See this post for a safe_mode redirection workaround: http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/blog/curl/php-curl-curlopt_followlocation-and-open_basedir-or-safe-mode/

Alternatively, run curl locally from the command line (under Cygwin for windows), and see if you can post your data to the find destination.  Running `curl -v` will show all the redirects which occur.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the URL using curl in a shell?

Comment: Hi, I don't have root access to my hosting account therefore I can't run any shell commands. But the host allows connections to port 80 so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Are you able to connect to other http resources using libcurl?  Some web hosts block out going connections.

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);

Comment: Also not working, after looking around a but more, I think it needs cookies aswell to authenticate... as I have a username and password cookie in my browser. I'll try and get cURL to accept the cookie.